# How to apply multi-criteria search to LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `WebForm` with 4 combo boxes, which allow user to define different search criteria. In case user selects nothing in a combo box, it does mean that user want to select all data in this criterion (in other words, omit the filter)

The idea is simple, but when I implement it in Linq, it painful. I don't know how to optionally add criteria into the query. Here is my "concept" query, which, of course, does not work:

```
var context = new Entities();
        var complaints = from c in context.Complaints
                         join s in context.Statuses on c.Status equals s.Id
                         join service in context.SERVICES on c.ServiceId equals service.Id
                         join u in context.Users on c.CreatedBy equals u.UserId
                         from technician in context.Users.Where(technician => technician.UserId == c.AssignedTo).DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where c.ResellerId == CurrentUser.ResellerID
                         && c.CreatedBy == (decimal)ASPxComboBoxSupporter.Value //if Supporter is selected and so on
                         && c.AssignedTo == (decimal)ASPxComboBoxTechnician.Value
                         && c.ServiceId == (decimal)ddlService.Value
                         && c.Status == (decimal)ddlStatus.Value
                         select new
                         {
                             c.Id,
                             c.Status,
                             s.Name,
                             c.ServiceId,
                             Service = service.Name,
                             c.Title,
                             c.Customer,
                             c.Description,
                             c.CreatedDate,
                             c.CreatedBy,
                             Author = u.Username,
                             c.AssignedBy,
                             c.AssignedTo,
                             Technician = technician.Username,
                             c.AssignedDate
                         };
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to parse the text input from the user to see if it's really a number or not, and if yes, convert it to the `decimal` type. There is a handy method `decimal.TryParse` for that:

```
    decimal supporter;
    bool supportedSpecified = decimal.TryParse( ASPxComboBoxSupporter.Value, out supporter );
```

And then you can use this information in the query:

```
    where c.ResellerId == CurrentUser.ResellerID
    && ( !supporterSpecified || c.CreatedBy == supporter )
    ...
```

Repeat for other criteria.

Comment: works great, but with a small flaw: decimal.TryParse cannot take first argument as object, but string. I changed to ASPxComboBoxSupporter.Value as string, and it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating it using the more SQL style Linq syntax (sorry I don't know the proper name for it), you could try taking advantage of the way IQueryable objects work. Basically what you can do is add where clauses where necessary, otherwise omit them. Something along these lines should work:

```
var context = new Entities();
var complaints = from c in context.Complaints
                 join s in context.Statuses on c.Status equals s.Id
                 join service in context.SERVICES on c.ServiceId equals service.Id
                 join u in context.Users on c.CreatedBy equals u.UserId
                 from technician in context.Users.Where(technician => technician.UserId == c.AssignedTo).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     c.Id,
                     c.Status,
                     s.Name,
                     c.ServiceId,
                     Service = service.Name,
                     c.Title,
                     c.Customer,
                     c.Description,
                     c.CreatedDate,
                     c.CreatedBy,
                     Author = u.Username,
                     c.AssignedBy,
                     c.AssignedTo,
                     Technician = technician.Username,
                     c.AssignedDate
                 };
```

So keep in mind you haven't actually queried anything yet, because Linq uses deferred execution. Now you can go through and add where clauses

```
if (ASPxComboBoxSupporter.Value != null)
{
    complaints = complaints.Where(c => c.CreatedBy == (decimal)ASPxComboBoxSupporter.Value);
}
if (ASPxComboBoxTechnician.Value != null)
{
    complaints = complaints.Where(c => c.AssignedTo == (decimal)ASPxComboBoxTechnician.Value);
}

if (ddlService.Value != null)
{
    complaints = complaints.Where(c => c.ServiceId == (decimal)ddlService.Value);
}

if (ddlStatus.Value != null)
{
    complaints = complaints.Where(c => c.Status == (decimal)ddlStatus.Value);
}
```

I haven't tested this, so let me know if something isn't working right still.

Comment: I actually implemented this as a solution to our own multi-criteria search and it works beautifully. It has the added benefit of only being complex when required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the PredicateBuilder class](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) described in the C# in a Nutshell book(s).  It allows you to dynamically build a predicate to use with LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework.